# How to check the checkboxes based on the input field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like `1,2` or `one, two` checks the first and second boxes.

I need a solution using **Javascript** or **JQuery**

```html
<input type="text" id="select" value="1,2" placeholder="type any thing">

<button id=submit> click </button>

<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> ph </th>
            <th> email </th>
            <th> reg no </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($studentlist as $list)
            <tr>
                <!-- THE CHECKBOXES -->
                <td>
                    <div class="checkbox p-0 mr-0">

                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ $list->studentid }}" name="checkbox[]"
                            id="checkbox-in-{{ $list->studentid }}">

                        <label for="checkbox-in-{{ $list->studentid }}"></label>

                    </div>
                </td>
                <td> {{ $list->studenName }} </td>
                <td> {{ $list->studentphnuumber }} </td>
                <td> {{ $list->email }} </td>
                <td> {{ $list->Regno }} </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: will you always have only 5 values ?

Comment: Instead of plain pasting something esoteric to us like the templating code, why didn't you used the generated code in browser? (Right click, Inspect Element, select the element, and on right click - Copy Outer HTML - paste it in the Question Code Snippet, Edit it, minify it and that's it - you got a [mcve])

Comment: @medilies that for eg

Comment: Than it would be a bit tricky to consider **integer** numbers and their **word counterpart**. If you are ready Accept a solution that only works with **integers** I may elaborate it. ALSO conider what @RokoC.Buljan said

Comment: @medilies hi if you  like to help me means .ping me coder_coder33 i instagram .i will explain you briefly

Comment: @medilies   codepen.io/medilies/pen/abVGpzL  opposite to this if field has 1,2 values means check box 1 and 2 should be selected

Comment: Yes I was thinking about giving you the reverse of that solution. But without considering `one , two`

Comment: @medilies that's enough to me with interger

Comment: @stopper did the answer work for you ?

Comment: @medilies wait i will update you shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const controlInput = document.querySelector("#select");
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

// Initial check
check(controlInput);

// Check on update
controlInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    check(e.target);
});

/**
 * @param {HTMLInputElement} controlInput
 */
function check(controlInput) {
    input = cleanInput(controlInput.value);

    const targetCheboxesIds = input.split(",");

    checkboxes.forEach((box) => {
        if (targetCheboxesIds.includes(box.id)) {
            box.checked = true;
        } else {
            box.checked = false;
        }
    });

    controlInput.value = input;
}

/**
 * @param {string} input
 */
function cleanInput(input) {
    // Removing white space and letters
    return input.replaceAll(/\s+/g, "").replaceAll(/[a-zA-Z]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<label>Students</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="select" placeholder="type any thing" value=",3,5">

<div>
  <label for="checkbox1"> 1 </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="1">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="checkbox2"> 2 </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="2">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="checkbox3"> 3 </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="3">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="checkbox4"> 4 </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="4">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="checkbox5"> 5 </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="5">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah its working ..but when  the value already present in the field  like 1.2 .without typing value manually  in the field .taking the value from field which already present (without manually writing).with that  values how to check the checkbox

Comment: Alright I didnt know about this case. I'll edit

Comment: @mediliies thank you so much  I change the code now  Its working  .thanks for the code :)

Comment: @stopper you are welcome :) check my update

Comment: @mediliies sure